# Google maps rectangle stops clicks on points beneath the rectangle on the map being detected

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a standard google maps set up with a click event that fires various code - works fine.

But when I add this rectangle to the map:

```
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 1,
                        fillOpacity: 0.0,
                        map: map,
                        bounds: bounds
                        });
```

It draws the rectangle perfectly but clicks on map points beneath the rectangle are not being detected, only clicks outside the perimeter of the rectangle.

Is there a quick/easy way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#RectangleOptions)

clickable: false

```
var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.0,
                    map: map,
                    bounds: bounds,
                    clickable: false
                    });
```

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was hoping for.